# Problems with JScrollPane -- Trying to Update it on Model Changes

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jscrollpane

I'm writing a fairly complex program, so I'll try to explain it only in terms of where the problem is occurring.

In my view, I create a JScrollPane to display a list of courses that a student is registered for:

```
registeredPane = new JScrollPane(); registeredPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
registeredPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
c.gridx = 2;
c.gridwidth = 1;
c.gridheight = 2;
c.weightx = 1;
c.weighty = 1;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
layout.setConstraints(registeredPane, c);
```

Then I, in my controller, change the model to reflect the courses the currently active student is registered in by calling this function in my model:

```
public void updateCurrentStudentCourses() {
ArrayList<String> courseNames = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Course c: currentStudent.getRegCourses()) {
courseNames.add("" + c.getDepartment().getId() + c.getCode());
}

System.out.println(courseNames);
}
```

Then I, again in my controller, update the view to reflect these changes by adding the 
ArrayList to the JScrollPane:

```
public void updateView() {
view.getNameField().setText(model.getCurrentStudent().getName());

view.getRegisteredPane().removeAll();
view.getRegisteredPane().getViewport().add(model.getCurrentStudentCourses());
view.getRegisteredPane().repaint();
}
```

The scrollbars disappear, but that's it.  The list items (which I know are in the ArrayList) are not displayed.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To which component of `Swing` are you adding those values of `ArrayLists`??

Comment: To the ArrayList I am adding Strings (course names) which the print call displays properly as [string1, string2, etc].  That's how I know that the ArrayList is fine.

Comment: `view.getNameField()` is returning a `JTextArea` object . right??

Comment: `JTextField`.  That part is unrelated.

Comment: `view.getNameField()` what this method is returning?

Comment: It's just a `String`, but that's not where the problem is.  What I'm trying to do is display an `ArrayList` of Strings in a `JScrollPane`.

Comment: I doubt if it is returning a `String` because `String` class doesn't have `setText()` method. It must throw compile time error while compilation..And you can't add `ArrayList` directly on the `JScrollPane` . Instead , you should put the contents of that `ArrayList` in a component like `JTextArea` or `JList` or whatever .. and then set the `viewport` of the `JScrollPane` to be that `component`.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, it's returning a `JTextField`, which I'm then grabbing the `String` out of.  That part is fine though.

Comment: Try to use solution..that I have posted..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**
If `model.getCurrentStudentCourses()` is returning an `ArrayList` then you can put the contents of `ArrayList` within `JTextArea` and then set the `viewport` of `JScrollPane` to be that `JTextArea`. You can proceed as follows:
your `updateView()` method should be like this:

```
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(30,100);
public void updateView() {
    ta.setText("");
    for (String course : model.getCurrentStudentCourses())
    ta.append(course+"\n");
    view.getNameField().setText(model.getCurrentStudent().getName());
    view.getRegisteredPane().setViewportView(ta);
}
```

Comment: This solution puts the student name into the JScrollPane, rather than the list of registered courses...it works, but not to the desired result.

Comment: `model.getCurrentStudentCourses()` what this method is returning?

Comment: +1 for trying to make sense of this question. @clappboard, then fix the code to do what you want. You've been given an approach, which is create a component to display the data you want displayed. Then you add that component to the view of the viewport. Your description of the problem is terribly confusing so understand the suggestion and fine tune it to your exact requrement. We don't know what kind of data your methods return.

Comment: I'm sorry for the trouble I've caused.  I've been rushing to get the code running, and in the process I've been changing it quite a bit.. If my answers were brief or rude, it was simply out a necessity to be quick.  I do appreciate all the answers and assistance I've gotten.  Marking this as solution, as it solved the problem and works well.
EDIT:  I agree.  +1 @VishalK.  My original post was scattered.  I'll edit it when I have time to help others.

Comment: @clappboard: since it is your first post (Question) on this site..so i could understand your eagerness and rush... It is always suggested to the questionnaire to post small ,short, Compile and run and understandable code..which let us to understand your problem clearly and provide the relevant and helpful answer to you..

Answer (score 1):

To set the view of a scrollpane, use [setViewportView()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setViewportView%28java.awt.Component%29). Manipulating the child components of the scrollpane directly will cause problems (for example, you're removing the scroll bars as well).

Scrollpanes have their own layout manager which only knows about the components created by the scrollpane (the various viewports, the scrollbars, the corners). So, any component you add will not appear unless you manually set its position.

Comment: This is good.  I was using the wrong method, but it's still asking me for a `Component`, not an ArrayList.  I guess I'll make an array of JLabels?

Comment: I think the suggestion has already been to use a JList or JTextArea. Making an array of JLabels does nothing because an array is not a component.